# Set custom size of NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, size, height, nstextfield

Is there a way to change NSTextField size?

It has three options in IB - regular, small and mini. Regular option has 22p in height, so I need for example 30.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default NSTextField's line break mode is clip (single line). To enable change its height You should change line break mode to Word Wrap.

[image]

Comment: I set line break mode to Word Wrap but I still unable to change `NSTextField` height

Comment: You are doing something wrong, that should work. Wait a sec I will create for You working source code.

Comment: I see. The problem was in rounded border style of my `NSTextField` - in this case height is fixed, if border isn't rounded - it can be changed